# SignIn with LinkedIn does not working with Cordova LinkedIn Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, linkedin-api

I am working on SignIn with LinkedIn functionality in my IONIC1 application. I have integrated "cordova-plugin-linkedin" plugin for Login wih LinkedIn and I also added required package name and hash. But when I try to run:

```
   var scopes = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 
                  'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];
   cordova.plugins.LinkedIn.login(scopes, true, function (response) {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(response);  
   }, function (error) {
       console.log("errror");
       console.log(error);
   });
```

It gives me an error like this in Error Response:

```
   {
      "errorMessage":"either bundle id or packagename / hash are 
                    invalid,unknown, malformed"
      "errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST"
   }
```